# Will I lose all of my data if I replace Windows with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, partitioning, disk

I wish to install Ubuntu OVER Windows. Windows is installed on my "C" partition. I also have another partition which contains 95% of my data.

I really would like to know if I install Ubuntu, will it delete all of my data on "D" partition? Or will it only overwrite on "C"? My goal is to install Ubuntu on "C" and keep all of my "D" partition data.

Comment: Replacing your operating system is a pretty serious undertaking. If your data is important, you ABSOLUTELY should have it backed up somewhere else! Data that is not backed up is data you don't care about.

Comment: Backup all your files just in case. If documents backkup to google drive. If photos uplaod to imgur or something.

Answer (score 4):

No you won't loose your data. Here are the steps you should take:

[image: Choose installation type]

Let's assume that your `C:/` drive is sda1, click on the `Change` button.

[image]

A window will pop up. Here you can set the size of the partition, its type and mount point. Check the box *Format the partition*, use `Ext4` and Mount point: `/` which means root.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

During the installation process, the installer asks you very specifically which disk and partition you wish to use to install ubuntu.  It will only erase and/or repartition what you tell it to.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that it will not erase my "D" data ?
I need to be 100% sure.