# Does choosing the "Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu" delete my drive data?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ubiquity

Quote from here: [Install Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)

> **Allocate drive space**
>
> Use the checkboxes to choose whether you'd like to Install Ubuntu
>   alongside another operating system, delete your existing operating
>   system and replace it with Ubuntu, or — if you're an advanced user —
>   choose the '**Something else**' option.

Question: does choosing the second option "**Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu**" delete my drive & drive data also, or does it only delete the C drive?

Comment: Yes, it will delete everything; it will delete your drive data. Read the answer to this question: [Will I lose all of my data if I replace Windows with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256155/will-i-lose-all-of-my-data-if-i-replace-windows-with-ubuntu) (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

**It will delete everything.**

When I say everything, I mean the whole drive. I don't have any documentation to show you right know, but I have experience on this. Recently I suggested this option to somebody and the whole drive reformatted. C:\ , D:\ .. everything.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing *replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu* wipes **everything** from the drive, if you're looking to replace Ubuntu with Win7 backup any data, if you aren't you can use the **partition tool** to *install Ubuntu along side Win7*