# Replacing win 7 with ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, format

Guys as u can see I want to install Ubuntu,not dual boot.

My question is when I select `Replace windows with Ubuntu`,will it delete all my data (complete hard disk format) or just windows 7 data (my `C:` drive) ??????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a better choice to select 'something else' and then when the installer asks for a location to install the root partition, just choose the `C:` drive. You will not lose data on any other drives (but **will** completely wipe out any data on `C:` such as Documents, Pictures, files/folders on Desktop, etc.) if you follow this procedure. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256155/will-i-lose-all-of-my-data-if-i-replace-windows-with-ubuntu) answer for more information.

Comment: This will however nuke any documents etc stored on the C drive, because Windows stores user data on it... always make backups so you have your data in case anything goes wrong

Comment: @Wilf Edited my answer to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: i mean it will format my C drive only or format my entire 1 TB hard disk?????

Comment: If you select 'Replace windows with Ubuntu' it will format your entire 1 TB disk. If you select 'something else' and then select your `c:` to mount your `/` it will only format your `c:` and **not** the entire 1TB disk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.

Windows holds all your data in one big partition, which occupies the whole drive (more or less) - this needs to be removed as a single item, so your data will go.

Save it to a removable drive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will, as opposed to dual boot or 'something else'.

If you are an Ubuntu "newbie" there are a few great options on trying ubuntu without deleting windows all together.

If the OP does not like a dual boot, visualization of windows is a great option if you wish to keep some windows functionality for specific programs.

I would suggest 4gig of Ram for this to be most effective on a 64bit Ubuntu OS.

A great guide for this is [VM Windows on Ubuntu](http://lifehacker.com/5623313/how-to-run-windows-mac-and-linux-side-by-side-and-pain-free-with-virtualbox/)